# Jetpack Compose Preview Render Issues with IntelliJ Not Showing the Problems

Tags: intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose

I am doing Android Native programming with Jetpack Compose, using the latest version of IntelliJ.

When trying to do a Preview of my Composable, after some recent changes, I am getting an error in the Preview window:
"Some issues were found while trying to render this preview".

[image]

When I click on the "Render Issues" button at the top of the Preview window, it shows me a popup that includes a link "View Problems".

[image]

The problem is that this link does absolutely nothing. It doesn't show me anything, so I have no idea what my render issues are.

Any ideas how I can actually see what the problems are with my preview? The preview was working before my latest changes. I obviously broke something, but I don't know what, since I can't see what the errors are.

UPDATE:

I still haven't figured out why I'm not seeing the errors when I click on the link, but I was able to find the errors in the IntelliJ log file, which is on my Mac in the following directory:
`~/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/idea.log`

My actual problem was that I needed to get application context, which I was storing in my main app file.

Comment: the ```Preview``` showing problem because of If you are using ```ViewModel``` in ```Compsable``` Parameters.

Comment: In general, if a Compose Preview is not rendering, it is usually due to non-default parameters.  As @Chirag Thummar suggested, this could be a ViewModel that is passed in, or any other parameter that wasn't given a default value.  

If you can post your code, we can offer more specific advise.

Comment: Thanks, @ChiragThummar and Jeremy Koppel. I was more looking to find a reason why I can't see an error list when I click on the problem link, so I can debug this and any other errors I come across in the future.
I am not using any ViewModels. I extracted my components from my "real" project and got rid of all ViewModels, just so I could use Previews. Thanks for letting me know I might be missing a value, that gives me something to look for. If I still can't fix the problem, I'll repost.

Answer (score 0):

### Simply click on the warning icon **here**

[image: Click on the warning icon on the Preview block (not on the top right one)]

**The one on the Preview Block**, not the one on the top right.